# Find the closest to a given natural number, which satisfies non-linear condition

Tags: algorithm, integer

I have three integers: `A`, `B`, `C` i need to find integer `X`, which is closest to `C`. If `N` is any natural number, then `A`, `B` and `X` should satisfy the following equation:

```
A*B*X=sqrt(N)
```

Could you help with algorithm?

Comment: Would you give us an example? Because for any chosen X we can always find N to satisfying the condition.

Comment: Wouldn't it be always x=c? Isn't any integer is a sqrt of a natural number?

Comment: for A=5,B=2,C=3, N will be 900 and X=3, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do a binary search over all possible values of `N`, and compare corresponding value of `X = sqrt(N)/(A*B))` to decide which half to carry on search.

A possible implementation in python could be -

```
A = 5
B = 2
C = 3

left = -10000000000000
right = 10000000000000 #assuming that's the maximum value N can take
while right-left>1:
    N = (left+right)//2
    X = N**.5/(A*B)
    if X>C:
        right = N
    else:
        left = N

N = (left+right)//2
print(N)
```

which in this case outputs: `900`